# Too many client connection at PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-13

I have 500 connection in my 3 node PostgreSQL cluster. But sometimes I found error like "too many clients already"
Why it show too many client connection? How does it calculate too many client connection?
RAM=8GB
CPU=8
SWAP=16GB
max_connection=500
but most of the time active connection is like 10-13. Idle connection like 480 to 490 and others 5 connection.

As per my understanding if active_connection+idle_connecton+other_reserve_connection>500 then it show too many client connection. If I am wrong please correct me.

In that case instantly how can I solve it?  Should I try below command to terminate current idle process?

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datname = 'databasename'
AND pid <> pg_backend_pid()
AND state in ('idle');
```

Is there any better solution than that? If you have any other way to solve this issue please lest me know. Need expert opinion.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: error message is: too many client connection

Comment: That is not an error message PostgreSQL will generate.  It must be coming from your client.

Comment: Use a connection pool and define its size limit much smaller than that.

Comment: Yes I am using pgpool. It is about 400(num_init_children) but what should be the amount. Is there any formula such as 80% of max_connection of database? If I set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=2min at database is there any benefit to get ride from this issue?